# How to avoid adding the react-toolbox css separately in index.html file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-toolbox

I'm using react-toolbox in my UI and my build tool is webpack. I have configured webpack to generate a style file - `react-toolbox.css` - in my `dist` directory. This file has the definitions for CSS classes that are used by react-toolbox components in my app. In my `index.html` this CSS file is added as an external link. My app styles(styles that I have writted for non react-toolbox components in my app) is `require`d in my `app.js` file and get loaded using the less-loader. Currently my app works fine.

- `app.js` is downloaded to provide the app scripts and app styles
- `react-toolbox.css` is downloaded to provide styles to the react-toolbox components

I wanted to know if there is a way to merge the contents of react-toolbox.css with my styles and require the resultant css inside `app.js`, thereby eliminating the need for a separate `react-toolbox.css`

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you can

> Bundled component
>
> You import from the index file so the imported component comes with
>   all dependencies and themes already required and injected for you.
>   This means that the CSS for each dependency will be bundled in your
>   final CSS automatically and the component markup includes the
>   classnames to be styled. For example:

```
import { AppBar } from 'react-toolbox/lib/app_bar';
```

**instead of**

```
import { AppBar } from 'react-toolbox/lib/app_bar/AppBar.js';
```

Comment: No. Bundled components just have classes added to them. That is what I'm using. I'm talking about the stylesheets